# Arduino not registering SPI transfer from STM32F407

Tags: arduino, embedded, stm32, spi

EDIT/SOLVED:  The issue ended up being my Serial.print statements in the Arduino code which were slowing down to execution of the actual communication code. Basically, the Arduino was receiving bytes after the STM board had finished sending them, so it was only registering 'd'/100.

I'm currently enrolled in an online course and facing an issue with one of the exercises. The exercise seems pretty straightforward, but I can't seem to get everything to work. The exercise is to send a string from a master MCU STM32F407 to an Arduino Uno board, which is then supposed to print the message and it's length.

The Arduino board seemed to register the SS, but would not print anything, print an incomplete/incorrect message (e.g. "hello vorl"), or print gibberish. After some debugging Idiscovered I had incorrectly set my CPOL and CPHA registers, however, now it won't print anything close to "Hello world." After more debugging, it seems like the Arduino is getting stuck in it's SPI_SlaveReceive function. The SPI code for the STM is designed to first send the length of the message and then send the actual message. From what I can tell, the Arduino doesn't seem to be registering the correct length for the first transmission, which is messing up the loop for the SPI_SlaveReceive calls that are supposed to grab the actual message.

I am new to embedded and have been trying to learn it mostly on my own. I feel like there is probably something basic that I am missing, but don't know about. I also feel as if the code is poorly designed, but I am trying to stick to the course (the STM code is "written" following guidelines and the arduino code was just provided). I will post the code below, but would even just appreciate ideas about what may be going wrong/how I can debug. Below everything I will also post some error logging.

This is also my first stackoverflow post, so please let me know if there is anything I need to add (or remove). Thanks!

Update:
I think it might be something with the clock speed. I tried running through the code again in a debugger and found that I was successfully able to send the data if I put a break point on the code that modifies the Data Register of the SPI. It seems like the SPI might be sending data more quickly than the Arduino can process. If I step through the code that sends the length of the message "Hello world" then I can see that the Arduino successfully received 11. If I continue to step through the pSPIx->DR = *pTxBuffer; instruction of the second call to the SPI_SendData, I can successfully send the message. However, if after sending the length, I try to step through the entirety of the second call to SPI_SendData in one step. The arduino doesn't register the entire string. I tried modifying the SPI pre-scalar to be greater values and this seemed to help. i.e. The arduino was able to output more valid characters (resulting in "hellod"). This confuses me however as the APB1 that controls SPI2 has a maximum freq of 42MHz. The pre-scalar value that I found gave me the best results was 7, which means the PCLK is divided by 256 resulting in, if I'm thinking about this correctly, a frequency of 164 MHz at most. Based on the specs of the Ardunio, it should have no problem processing this communication. I'm thinking I might have a problem is how often the bits are sent? Maybe my SPI_SendData function isn't working correctly?

Other details:

- 4 wires connecting the boards: GND, CLK (STM: PB13 <-> UNO: 13), MOSI (STM: PB15 <-> A: 11), and NSS (STM: PB12 <-> A:10)
- I don't have a logic analyzer, so I haven't been able to see what's actually being sent (which sucks)
- I realize it may be hard to get the full context without posting all of the code, but I figured that would be too much, so tried to just post the relevant parts.

Logging:

```
16:01:42.461 -> Slave Initialized
16:01:42.494 -> Slave waiting for ss to go low
16:01:45.500 -> slave selected
16:01:45.500 -> Waiting to receive length
16:01:45.534 -> Length: 68
16:01:47.520 -> Received: 
16:01:47.554 -> Received: d
16:01:48.968 -> Received: 
16:01:48.968 -> Received: d
16:01:49.858 -> Received: 
16:01:49.858 -> Received: d
16:01:50.499 -> Received: 
16:01:50.499 -> Received: d
16:01:51.137 -> Received: 
16:01:51.137 -> Received: d
16:01:51.707 -> Received: 
16:01:51.741 -> Received: d
16:01:52.244 -> Received: 
16:01:52.277 -> Received: d
16:01:52.782 -> Received: 
16:01:52.782 -> Received: d
16:01:53.360 -> Received: 
16:01:53.393 -> Received: d
16:01:53.866 -> Received: 
16:01:53.899 -> Received: d
16:01:54.441 -> Received: 
16:01:54.441 -> Received: d
16:01:54.946 -> Received: 
16:01:54.980 -> Received: d
16:01:55.484 -> Received: 
16:01:55.518 -> Received: d
16:01:55.994 -> Received: 
16:01:56.027 -> Received: d
16:01:56.599 -> Received: 
16:01:56.599 -> Received: d
16:01:57.105 -> Received: 
16:01:57.138 -> Received: `
16:01:57.609 -> Received: 
16:01:57.644 -> Received: d
16:01:58.085 -> Received: 
16:01:58.118 -> Received: d
16:01:58.622 -> Received: 
16:01:58.622 -> Received: d
16:01:59.128 -> Received: 
16:01:59.161 -> Received: d
16:01:59.676 -> Received: 
16:01:59.676 -> Received: d
16:02:00.146 -> Received: 
16:02:00.180 -> Received: d
16:02:00.654 -> Received: 
16:02:00.654 -> Received: d
16:02:01.127 -> Received: 
16:02:01.127 -> Received: d
16:02:01.634 -> Received: 
16:02:01.668 -> Received: d
16:02:02.105 -> Received: 
16:02:02.139 -> Received: d
16:02:02.582 -> Received: 
16:02:02.582 -> Received: d
16:02:03.052 -> Received: 
16:02:03.052 -> Received: d
16:02:03.729 -> Received: 
16:02:03.729 -> Received: d
16:02:04.236 -> Received: 
16:02:04.236 -> Received: d
16:02:04.774 -> Received: 
16:02:04.774 -> Received: d
16:02:05.336 -> Received: 
16:02:05.336 -> Received: d
16:02:05.947 -> Received: 
16:02:05.980 -> Received: d
16:02:06.485 -> Received: 
16:02:06.485 -> Received: d
16:02:06.518 -> done receiving word
16:02:06.518 -> Rcvd:
16:02:06.553 -> ddddddddddddddd`dddddddddddddddddd
16:02:06.620 -> Length:68
16:02:06.620 -> Slave deselected
16:02:06.654 -> Slave waiting for ss to go low
16:02:07.025 -> slave selected
16:02:07.058 -> Waiting to receive length
16:02:07.092 -> Length: 100
```

Arduino code:

```
/* SPI Slave Demo
 *
 * SPI pin numbers:
 * SCK   13  // Serial Clock.
 * MISO  12  // Master In Slave Out.
 * MOSI  11  // Master Out Slave In.
 * SS    10  // Slave Select . Arduino SPI pins respond only if SS pulled low by the master
 *

 */
#include <SPI.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#define SPI_SCK 13
#define SPI_MISO 12
#define SPI_MOSI 11
#define SPI_SS 10

char dataBuff[500];
//Initialize SPI slave.
void SPI_SlaveInit(void) 
{ 
 #if 0 
  // Initialize SPI pins.
  pinMode(SPI_SCK, INPUT);
  pinMode(SPI_MOSI, INPUT);
  pinMode(SPI_MISO, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SPI_SS, INPUT);

  // Enable SPI as slave.
  SPCR = (1 << SPE);
 #endif 
   // Initialize SPI pins.
  pinMode(SCK, INPUT);
  pinMode(MOSI, INPUT);
  pinMode(MISO, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SS, INPUT);
  //make SPI as slave

  // Enable SPI as slave.
  SPCR = (1 << SPE);

}

//This function returns SPDR Contents 
uint8_t SPI_SlaveReceive(void)
{
  /* Wait for reception complete */
  while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)));
  /* Return Data Register */
  return SPDR;
}


//sends one byte of data 
void SPI_SlaveTransmit(char data)
{
  /* Start transmission */
  SPDR = data;

  /* Wait for transmission complete */
  while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)));
}


// The setup() function runs right after reset.
void setup() 
{
  // Initialize serial communication 
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Initialize SPI Slave.
  SPI_SlaveInit();

  Serial.println("Slave Initialized");
}
 uint16_t dataLen = 0;
  uint32_t i = 0;
// The loop function runs continuously after setup().
void loop() 
{



  Serial.println("Slave waiting for ss to go low");
  while(digitalRead(SS) );
  Serial.println("slave selected");

 //  Serial.println("start");

  //1. read the length  
//  dataLen = (uint16_t)( SPI_SlaveReceive() | (SPI_SlaveReceive() << 8) );
  //Serial.println(String(dataLen,HEX));
 i = 0;
  Serial. println("Waiting to receive length");
  dataLen = SPI_SlaveReceive();
  for(i = 0 ; i < dataLen ; i++ )
  {
    dataBuff[i] =  SPI_SlaveReceive();
    Serial.print("Received: ");
    Serial.println(dataBuff[i]);
  }
  Serial.println("done receiving word");

  //  Serial.println(String(i,HEX));
  dataBuff[i] = '\0';

  Serial.println("Rcvd:");
  Serial.println(dataBuff);
  Serial.print("Length:");
  Serial.println(dataLen);

  while(!digitalRead(SS));
  Serial.println("Slave deselected");


}
```

Main STM code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include "stm32f407xx.h"


/*
 * PB15 --> SPI2_MOSI
 * PB14 --> SPI2_MISO
 * PB13 --> SPI2_SCLK
 * PB12 --> SPI2_NSS
 * ALT Function mode: 5
 */

void SPI_GPIO_Setup(void);
void GPIO_ButtonInit(void);
void SPI_Setup(void);

void delay(int time){
    for(uint32_t i=0; i<time; i++);
}

int main(void) {

    char userData[] = "Hello world";

    //initizalize button
    GPIO_ButtonInit();

    //This function is used to initialize the gpio pins to behave as spi pins
    SPI_GPIO_Setup();

    //This function is used to initialize the SPI peripheral
    SPI_Setup();

    //this makes NSS signal internally high and avoids MODF error
    //NOTE: This should be taken care of in my SPI_Init function
//  SPI_SSIConfig(SPI2, ENABLE);

    //SSOE to 1 does NSS output enable
    //I don't want to enable this in this way, but it is more simple due to the code design
    //i.e. (using shifts instead of masks for registers)
    SPI_SSOEConfig(SPI2, ENABLE);

    while(1){
        //wait for button to be pressed
        while(! GPIO_ReadFromInputPin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_0));

        delay(250000); //used for button debouncing

        //enable the SPI2 peripheral --- according to generated code, this seems to be done in the transmit function
        // I a SET_BIT macro in the transmit function if SPI isn't enabled, make sure to test this
        SPI_PeripheralControl(SPI2, ENABLE);

        //first send the length of data (Arduino expects this as 1 byte)
        uint8_t dataLen = strlen(userData);
        SPI_SendData(SPI2, &dataLen, 1);

        //send data
        SPI_SendData(SPI2, (uint8_t*)userData, dataLen);

        //confirm the SPI is not busy
        while(SPI_GetFlagStatus(SPI2, SPI_BSY_FLAG));

        //disable the SPI2 peripheral --- according to Generated code, this seems to be done in abort functions
        SPI_PeripheralControl(SPI2, DISABLE);
    }

    return 0;
}

void SPI_GPIO_Setup(void) {

    GPIO_Handle_t SPIpins;

    SPIpins.pGPIOx = GPIOB;
    SPIpins.GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinMode = GPIO_MODE_ALTFN;
    SPIpins.GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinAltFunMode = 5;
    SPIpins.GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinOPType = GPIO_OPTYPE_PP;
    SPIpins.GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinPuPdControl = GPIO_PU;
    SPIpins.GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinSpeed = GPIO_SPEED_FAST;

    //MOSI
    SPIpins.GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber = GPIO_PIN_15;
    GPIO_Init(&SPIpins);


    //MISO
//  SPIpins.GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber = GPIO_PIN_14;
//  GPIO_Init(&SPIpins);

    //SCLK
    SPIpins.GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber = GPIO_PIN_13;
    GPIO_Init(&SPIpins);

    //NSS
    SPIpins.GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber = GPIO_PIN_12;
    GPIO_Init(&SPIpins);


}
void GPIO_ButtonInit(void){
    GPIO_Handle_t GpioBtn;

    // configure button
    //Set up PA0 to be an input for the button press
    GpioBtn.pGPIOx = GPIOA;
    GpioBtn.GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber = GPIO_PIN_0;
    GpioBtn.GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinMode = GPIO_MODE_IN;
    GpioBtn.GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinSpeed = GPIO_SPEED_FAST;
    GpioBtn.GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinPuPdControl = GPIO_NO_PUPD;
    GPIO_Init(&GpioBtn);
}
void SPI_Setup(void){
    SPI_Handle_t hSPI;

    hSPI.SPIx = SPI2;
    hSPI.SPIConfig.SPI_BusConfig = SPI_BUS_CONFIG_FD;
    hSPI.SPIConfig.SPI_DeviceMode = SPI_DEVICE_MODE_MASTER;
    hSPI.SPIConfig.SPI_SclkSpeed = SPI_SCLK_SPEED_DIV8; //generate SCLK of 2 MHz
    hSPI.SPIConfig.SPI_DFF = SPI_DFF_8BITS;
    hSPI.SPIConfig.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_LOW;
    hSPI.SPIConfig.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_LOW;
    hSPI.SPIConfig.SPI_SSM = SPI_SSM_DI; //Hardware slave management disabled for NSS pin

    SPI_Init(&hSPI);
}
```

SPI Driver code:

```
    /*
 * stm32f407xx_spi_driver.c
 *
 *  Created on: Oct 17, 2019
 *      Author: pigmo
 */

#include "stm32f407xx_spi_driver.h"

/**************************************************************************
 *                  APIs supported by this driver
 * For more information about these APIs check the function description
 **************************************************************************/
/*
 * Peripheral clock setup
 */

/******************************************************
 * @fn                  - SPI_PeriClockControl
 *
 * @brief               - Enables or disables peripheral clock for the given SPI port
 *
 * @param[in]           - base address of SPI peripheral
 * @param[in]           - ENABLE or DISABLE macros
 *
 * @return              - none
 *
 * @Note                - SPI4 is reserved and won't be affected by this function
 */
void SPI_PeriClockControl(SPI_RegDef_t* pSPIx, uint8_t enOrDi){
    if(enOrDi == ENABLE){
            if(pSPIx == SPI1){
                SPI1_PCLK_EN();
            } else if (pSPIx == SPI2){
                SPI2_PCLK_EN();
            } else if (pSPIx == SPI3){
                SPI3_PCLK_EN();
            }
        } else {
            if(pSPIx == SPI1){
                SPI1_PCLK_DI();
            } else if (pSPIx == SPI2){
                SPI2_PCLK_DI();
            } else if (pSPIx == SPI3){
                SPI3_PCLK_DI();
            }
        }
}

/*
 * Init and De-init
 */

/******************************************************
 * @fn                  - SPI_Init
 *
 * @brief               - Initializes a given GPIO peripheral with given configurations
 *
 * @param[in]           - Struct holding base address and desired configurations of SPI peripheral
 *
 * @return              - none
 *
 * @Note                - I don't like the way this is done, but I'm doing it to be consistent with the course
 *                          Instead, I think the SPIConfig should hold masks, not enum type values
 */
void SPI_Init(SPI_Handle_t *pSPIHandle){

    //enable the spi clock
    SPI_PeriClockControl(pSPIHandle->SPIx, ENABLE);

    //disable the SPI (concept taken from STM generated code)
    SPI_PeripheralControl(pSPIHandle->SPIx, DISABLE);

    //first configure the SPI CR1 register
    uint32_t tempReg = 0;

    //1. configure the device mode
    if(pSPIHandle->SPIConfig.SPI_DeviceMode == SPI_DEVICE_MODE_MASTER){
        // if the device is master mode, then the SSI must also be 1 to avoid an error (unless Multi master?)
        // this is only true if SSM is enabled, can we keep this functionality even is SSM is disabled?
        // based on stm generated code, the SSI stays enabled for SSM enabled and disabled
        tempReg |= pSPIHandle->SPIConfig.SPI_DeviceMode << SPI_CR1_MSTR;
        tempReg |= (1 << SPI_CR1_SSI); // this should probably be done in another way
    } else {
        tempReg |= pSPIHandle->SPIConfig.SPI_DeviceMode << SPI_CR1_MSTR;
    }

    //2. configure the bus config
    if(pSPIHandle->SPIConfig.SPI_BusConfig == SPI_BUS_CONFIG_FD){
        //bdi should be cleared
        tempReg &= ~(1 << SPI_CR1_BIDIMODE);
    } else if(pSPIHandle->SPIConfig.SPI_BusConfig == SPI_BUS_CONFIG_HD){
        //bdi should be set
        tempReg |= ~(1 << SPI_CR1_BIDIMODE);
    } else {
        //bdi should be cleared
        tempReg &= ~(1 << SPI_CR1_BIDIMODE);
        //RXONLY should be set
        tempReg |= (1 << SPI_CR1_RXONLY);
    }

    //3. configure the clock speed
    tempReg |= (pSPIHandle->SPIConfig.SPI_SclkSpeed << SPI_CR1_BR);

    //4. configure the Data frame format
    tempReg |= (pSPIHandle->SPIConfig.SPI_DFF << SPI_CR1_DFF);

    //5. configure the clock polarity
    tempReg |= (pSPIHandle->SPIConfig.SPI_CPOL << SPI_CR1_CPOL);

    //6. configure the clock phase
    tempReg |= (pSPIHandle->SPIConfig.SPI_CPHA << SPI_CR1_CPHA);

    //7. determine hardware or software slave management
    tempReg |= (pSPIHandle->SPIConfig.SPI_SSM << SPI_CR1_SSM);

    pSPIHandle->SPIx->CR1 = tempReg;
}

/******************************************************
 * @fn                  - SPI_DeInit
 *
 * @brief               - Deinitializes a given SPI periphal and resets register
 *
 * @param[in]           - base address of SPI peripheral
 *
 * @return              - none
 *
 * @Note                - none
 */
void SPI_DeInit(SPI_RegDef_t* pSPIx){
    if(pSPIx == SPI1){
        SPI1_REG_RESET();
    } else if (pSPIx == SPI2){
        SPI2_REG_RESET();
    } else if (pSPIx == SPI3){
        SPI3_REG_RESET();
    }
}

/*
 * Data send and receive
 */

uint8_t SPI_GetFlagStatus(SPI_RegDef_t* pSPIx, uint32_t flag){
    if(pSPIx->SR & flag){
        return SET;
    } else {
        return RESET;
    }
}

/******************************************************
 * @fn                  - SPI_SendData
 *
 * @brief               - sends data of length len to transmit buffer
 *
 * @param[in]           - base address of SPI peripheral
 * @param[in]           - address of Tx buffer
 * @param[in]           - length of data to send
 *
 * @return              - none
 *
 * @Note                - This is a blocking call
 */
//actual code seems much more complex, check that out
void SPI_SendData(SPI_RegDef_t* pSPIx, uint8_t *pTxBuffer, uint32_t len){
    //if SPi is not enabled, then enable it
    if((pSPIx->CR1 & (1 << SPI_CR1_SPE)) != (1 << SPI_CR1_SPE)){
        SET_BIT(pSPIx->CR1, (1 << SPI_CR1_SPE)); // this is repetitive, should just have a mask,
    }

    while(len > 0) {
        //1. Wait until Tx is empty
        while(SPI_GetFlagStatus(pSPIx, SPI_TXE_FLAG) ==  RESET);

        //2. Check DFF in CR1
        if (pSPIx->CR1 & (1 << SPI_CR1_DFF) ) {
            //16 bit dff
            //3. load data into DR
            pSPIx->DR = *((uint16_t*)pTxBuffer);
            len--;
            len--;
            (uint16_t*)pTxBuffer++;
        } else {
            //8 bit dff
            //3. load data into DR
            pSPIx->DR = *pTxBuffer;
            len--;
            pTxBuffer++;
        }

    }
}

/******************************************************
 * @fn                  - SPI_ReceiveData
 *
 * @brief               - Receives data of length len to Receive buffer
 *
 * @param[in]           - base address of SPI peripheral
 * @param[in]           - address of Rx buffer
 * @param[in]           - length of data to Receive
 *
 * @return              - none
 *
 * @Note                - none
 */
void SPI_ReceiveData(SPI_RegDef_t* pSPIx, uint8_t *pRxBuffer, uint32_t len){

}

/*
 * IRQ configuration and handling
 */

/******************************************************
 * @fn                  - SPI_IRQITConfig
 *
 * @brief               - enables or disables a SPI peripherals IRQ functionality
 *
 * @param[in]           - IRQ number of SPI peripheral
 * @param[in]           - ENABLE or DISABLE macros
 *
 * @return              - none
 *
 * @Note                - none
 */
void SPI_IRQInterruptConfig(uint8_t IRQNumber, uint8_t enOrDi){

}

/******************************************************
 * @fn                  - SPI_IRQPriorityConfig
 *
 * @brief               - sets the priority for a given IRQ number
 *
 * @param[in]           - IRQ priority of SPI peripheral
 * @param[in]           - IRQ number of SPI peripheral
 *
 * @return              - none
 *
 * @Note                - modifies the NVIC peripheral
 */
void SPI_IRQPriorityConfig(uint8_t IRQPriority, uint8_t IRQNumber){

}

/******************************************************
 * @fn                  - SPI_IRQHandling
 *
 * @brief               - deals with a interrupt triggered by a SPI pin
 *
 * @param[in]           - Struct holding base address and desired configurations of SPI peripheral
 *
 * @return              - none
 *
 * @Note                - none
 */
void SPI_IRQHandling(SPI_Handle_t *pHandle){

}

/******************************************************
 * @fn                  - SPI_PeripheralControl
 *
 * @brief               - Enables or Disables SPI
 *
 * @param[in]           - Pointer to a SPI register
 *
 * @return              - none
 *
 * @Note                - I'm implementing this in the transmit function
 */
void SPI_PeripheralControl(SPI_RegDef_t *pSPIx, uint8_t enOrDi){
    if(enOrDi == ENABLE){
        pSPIx->CR1 |= (1 << SPI_CR1_SPE);
    } else {
        pSPIx->CR1 &= ~(1 << SPI_CR1_SPE);
    }
}

/******************************************************
 * @fn                  - SPI_SSIConfig
 *
 * @brief               - Sets or Resets SSI bit in SPI CR1 reg
 *
 * @param[in]           - Pointer to a SPI register
 *
 * @return              - none
 *
 * @Note                - This code is used in the course I'm following,
 *                      but I think it is redundant and bad practice. It will not be used.
 *                      Instead, I implemented a check in the SPI init function to enable SSI w/ master
 */
void SPI_SSIConfig(SPI_RegDef_t *pSPIx, uint8_t enOrDi){
    if(enOrDi == ENABLE){
        pSPIx->CR1 |= (1 << SPI_CR1_SSI);
    } else {
        pSPIx->CR1 &= ~(1 << SPI_CR1_SSI);
    }
}

/******************************************************
 * @fn                  - SPI_SSOEConfig
 *
 * @brief               - Sets or Resets SSOE bit in SPI CR2 reg
 *
 * @param[in]           - Pointer to a SPI register
 *
 * @return              - none
 *
 * @Note                - This code is used in the course I'm following,
 *                      but I think it is redundant and bad practice. I will use it bec of consistency
 *                      Otherwise, in the STM generated code, this bit is determine by a NSS value in the init struct
 *                      See: WRITE_REG(hspi->Instance->CR2, (((hspi->Init.NSS >> 16U) & SPI_CR2_SSOE) | hspi->Init.TIMode));
 */
void SPI_SSOEConfig(SPI_RegDef_t *pSPIx, uint8_t enOrDi){
    if(enOrDi == ENABLE){
        pSPIx->CR2 |= (1 << SPI_CR2_SSOE);
    } else {
        pSPIx->CR2 &= ~(1 << SPI_CR2_SSOE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try all combinations of CPHA and CPOL?

Comment: I just tried all 4 combinations and it did not seem to make a difference

Comment: You said that you don't have a logic analyzer. But do you have an oscilloscope?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't. Everything seems so expensive. Would it be worth saving up for one/are there cheaper options?

Comment: If you plan to play a lot with Arduinos and hardware, I'd say yes, it's worth. You will learn a lot and be faster with error analysis. -- You can get some hobbyist's device as second-hand or on sales for under $100, or any equivalent value in your currency. -- I bought an DSO203 as an Easter present for myself when they were on sale two years ago for under €100. This is a digital storage oscilloscope that is partly open source on hardware and application software. -- Beware, don't buy any AVR based device cheaper than $40, these are just toys and you will be heavily disappointed.

Comment: Hi, I have the exact  same problem and I am also doing the same course.Did you find the solution to this problem?